# Two different marriage dates for the same couple?

Tags: england, marriage-records, 1820s, yorkshire

I'm digging through online records and researching Charles and Mary Ann Kirby (listed as maiden name of Hart) who came to Canada from Yorkshire England. I found one record that has their wedding as taking place on May 11,1828 in Allerthorpe by Pocklington, York England and another with the same couple  on May 17th, same year, same location. Would this be their banns? Both are listed as a wedding hence my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that the two records are on FamilySearch.

**[Record 1](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NNR4-TLD)**

> Charles Kerby & Mary Ann Hart
>   11 May 1828
>   Allerthorpe, York, England
>   Film 2104781

**[Record 2](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NL6B-QQQ)**

> Charles Kirby & Mary Ann Hart
>   17 May 1828
>   Allerthorpe By Pocklington,York,England
>   Film 990927

You need to find out what record is being indexed in each case. Using the [FamilySearch Catalog](https://familysearch.org/catalog/search), search for the film number.

- **[Film 2104781](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&query=%2Bfilm_number%3A2104781)** contains [Parish registers for Allerthorpe, 1616-1901](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/988689?availability=Family%20History%20Library), originally sourced from the Borthwick Institute (PR/ALL 8).
- **[Film 990927](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&query=%2Bfilm_number%3A990927)** contains [Bishop's transcripts for Allerthorpe, 1600-1848](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/182687?availability=Family%20History%20Library), also originally sourced from the Borthwick Institute.

Therefore, the discrepancy is either an inconsistency between the Parish Register and Bishop's Transcript, or an indexing error of one or both records.

It was a good thought to consider that one might be a record of banns, however that appears to not be the case in this instance.

The only way to determine the correct date is to look at the original Parish Register/Bishop's Transcript. This can be done by:

- [ordering the film](https://familysearch.org/films/) via FamilySearch and viewing at it at one of their Family History Centres; or
- visiting or [ordering a copy from Borthwick](https://www.york.ac.uk/borthwick/remote-services/copying/)

However, [Findmypast](http://findmypast.co.uk) also has images of the parish register, where the date is spelt out as "this seventeenth day of May" so the error of 11th arose at some point in the sequence of transcription/indexing of the original parish register.  The banns records don't seem to be present on Findmypast. The image of the BTs also says "seventeenth".

Comment: I had also looked on freewebmd( I think thats how its spelled) and came up with the same results. 
I will definitely have to go to one of the search centres to see what I can find.
Thanks again!

Comment: It is common that 7 and 1 are easily confused in old records.

Answer (score 1):

I just participated in the Family Search Indexing transcribing mostly marriage records. However, on some records, it was only the application, not the actual marriage. I chose not to enter those and requested some help on what to do but never got it. So, someone could have transcribed the application date for the marriage date as "application" was not an option for the form.

The marriages were in America. The titles just said application. I assume it was application for a license to marry, which doesn't prove they actually married or when, which is why I didn't enter them as marriages. But some people would.

Comment: Welcome, Debbie! By application do you mean record of banns? Or marriage bond or allegation? In England there is no such thing as a marriage application.